# Design an experiment to identify a (binary) category

Tags: bayesian, binomial-distribution, experiment-design

There are two types of alien, *type A* and *type B*, on a newly discovered planet. You have noticed that *type A* aliens seem to enjoy listening to the Beatles more than *type B* aliens. Specifically, you note that,

$$P(\mbox{dance to a Beatles song} ~|~ \mbox{type A}) \geq 0.5,$$

and,

$$P(\mbox{dance to a Beatles song} ~|~ \mbox{type B}) = 0.25.$$

Furthermore, you know that there are equal numbers of *type A* and *type B* aliens, so that,

$$P(\mbox{type A})=P(\mbox{type B})=0.5.$$

**Question:** Design an experiment with $N$ questions to determine, with 95% confidence, whether a given alien is of *type A* or *type B*. What is the smallest size $N$ for such an experiment?

Specifically, I want to know if it is possible to do better than the following.

#### Binomial Calculation

Let $X$ denote the Bernoulli random variable that is 1 if the alien dances, and 0 otherwise. Our experiment consists of $N$ draws $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ (think of playing $N$ different songs and seeing if they dance each time).

**Experiment:** Fix $N, \tau$. Say alien is *type A*  if $Y_N := \sum_{i=1}^N X_i \geq \tau$, otherwise they are of *type B*. From the binomial distribution we have,

$$P(Y_N \geq \tau ~|~ \mbox{type A}) \geq \sum_{i = \tau}^N {N \choose i} (0.5)^i(0.5)^{N-i}$$

$$P(Y_N < \tau ~|~ \mbox{type B}) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\tau - 1} {N \choose i} (0.25)^i(0.75)^{N-i}$$

It remains to find $N$ and $\tau$ such that,

$$P(Y_N \geq \tau ~\cap~ \mbox{type A}) + P(Y_N < \tau ~\cap~ \mbox{type B}) \geq 0.95,$$

or equivalently,

$$P(Y_N \geq \tau ~|~ \mbox{type A})\cdot P(\mbox{type A}) + P(Y_N < \tau ~|~ \mbox{type B})\cdot P(\mbox{type B}) \geq 0.95.$$

Solving this we see that the minimum $N, \tau$ pair is,

$$N = 39, \tau = 15.$$